# How to use OAuth 2.0 with a Google Apps Script library, with a static redirect URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0, asana-api, asana-connect

I can't figure out how to make a *shared* Google Apps Script library, that uses OAuth 2.0.

The problem is that the `usercallback` redirect URL changes, every time I use the library in a different script. However, that means I'd need to add a new app and whitelisted redirect URL to Asana for each spreadsheet I use the script in. I'm using https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2.

Is there a way to always authenticate with the same redirect URL, so that the library I make can be used from any script, without registering a new redirect URL in Asana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Developer Advocate here at Asana. If I understand your question correctly, then yes, you'll have to handle the callback separately for each script. For security reasons, we validate that the OAuth app registration registers the *same* url as an integration actually requests when authenticating. If this weren't true, for instance, it'd be possible to create a malicious script that uses the `client_id` from a legitimate script but asks for the redirect to go to its own credential-grabbing endpoint. This is fixed if the app that got the `client_id` on app registration also specifies precisely which endpoint should be the legal endpoint to redirect to. That means each OAuth app needs to have its own unique and consistent redirect URL :(

I suppose you could possibly create a single "router" Google Apps script which would set the `state` parameter with some user/script pair when hitting Asana's [oauth_authorize endpoint](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#user-authorization) and forward the user credentials on to the script that exists behind the router script based on that user/script pair when the response comes back, but it's not super trivial.

One final option would be to use a [Personal Access Token](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#personal-access-token) to access Asana's API. This one token can be used by an unlimited number of scripts for access. The downside is that this token "looks like you", that is, it takes action on behalf of not a third party user but you yourself - your scripts would be an automated version of the user whose Personal Access Token they use. This can be mitigated to some extent by creating a "bot account" to access our API and giving it access inside of Asana to the projects or teams you want to gather data on. The other downside to this approach is that every script that uses the personal access token will break if you ever revoke the one token, so if that ever happens by either intent or accident, you'll have to update the Personal Access Token information in every script that uses it.

Hopefully this helps you to evaluate the options and choose which one of these options works best for your script.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have written a custom formula that pulls down all the tasks for a given project. The problem is that let's say we make one spreadsheet per sprint or project, that means we'd have to add new apps to Asana for every spreadsheet we made - obviously not great. It sounds like the middle solution to create an apps script that has a permanent web service URL, could work so I'll probably go down that route. I considered a Personal Access Token, but that exposes all my private tasks, and a bot account would cost $. Ideally we could share this with the world too.